# typescript incorrectly finds types from module

Tags: javascript, typescript, tsc

In my package.json, **module1** version **1** and **module2** version **2** are listed as dependencies.
In addition, package **module1** has **module2** version **1** as its dependencies

And when I use **module2** in my code

> const { SomeClass } = require('module2');

vscode and tsc signal me

> Namespace '"{project_path}/node_modules/module1/node_modules/module2/dist/index"' has no exported member 'SomeClass'

How can I make tsc use exactly the version of the module that is specified in my root package.json?

Answer (score 0):

After adding this code to my tsconfig.json the problem was solved

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
       ...,
       "paths": {
           "*": [
               "./node_modules/*"
           ]
       }
   },
   ...
}
```